# How to get password when Spring security used login

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring security for login.I need to get password from spring security.If anyone know please give me one solution.Urgent

Comment: explain better. You shouldn't retrieve the password yourslef. Your user should provide the password and Spring Security performs the matching to verify whether the user is to be authenticated or not.

Comment: Why I need because I didnt store password in database.Now I have put password static way.This password I need for login database also>Is there anyway to get password

Comment: if you use a security framework like the one you mentioned, you should allow the framework to manage security aspects. You don't need to check the password yourself. Spring Security has something called Authentication Manager that is there to perform athentication procedures. I strongly advice you to read [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/). You'll find all the answer you need.